# Are $6$ and $626$ the only palindromic numbers of the form form $5^x+1$?

Tags: number-theory, palindrome

I noticed that $5^1+1=6$ and $5^4+1=626$ are both palindromic numbers.

Are there any palindromic numbers other than $6$ and $626$ that is form of $5^x+1$? X must be a positive integer.

I think there are other palindromic numbers that is form of $5^x+1$, since $5^{14}+1$ starts with $6$ and the first 3 digits of powers of 5 can be $626$.

Comment: There is $5^1+1=6=6$ too, if it counts...

Comment: I have downvoted the question as it comes across as a bit random, probably due to lack of context or motivation behind the question. If you provide more context/motivation then I will remove my downvote (and maybe even upvote :o)

Comment: Probably, though it seems very hard to prove. You can show that there’s infinitely many $5^n$ with any given leading digits while the end digits repeat, so you can get infinitely terms with any number of matching digits between the front and the back. You can use a heuristic that $1/10^{n/2}$ $n$ digit numbers are palindromes to get that there’s likely $1/(1-1/5^{0.5})\approx 2$ solutions, so it’s likely that that’s all of them.

Comment: I cannot understand the upvotes 1. No search limit is given (how far has the problem be checked ?) 2. It is not clarified what $x$ exactly can be. If it is allowed to be $0$ , we have a third palindrome. 3. The problem is quite random.

Comment: Upto $x=10^4$ , there is no further palindrome , so chances for another palindrome are near $0$.

Comment: Extended to $10^5$

Comment: Just an idea: when a palindrome number consists of an even number of digits, it is automatically divisible by 11. Might this help proving this (im)possibility?

Comment: Extended to $10^{10}$

Comment: @Dominique, I proved $5^x+1$ has no palindrome with even number of digits using your hint. But for odd digits, it's not trivial. There's a symmetry which this can be helpful: $10^{4j+2}+1\equiv 0 \mod 101$, $10^{4j}+1\equiv 2 \mod 101$